# как собрать паскаль-программу через gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, freepascal

Умеет ли GCC собирать код FreePascal, и если да, то как это сделать?
Для "Духа сообщества": При сборке

```
fpc proga.pas
```

программа получается очень большой.
Есть опыт компиляции исходников Си через GCC с параметрами для уменьшения выходного бинарника.
Вот и хотелось бы уточнить, GCC/LLVM могут собирать исходники Паскаль?

Comment: Вы с GPC не путаете?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Был когда-то GNU Pascal, он же GPC (работавший поверх gcc), но заброшен где-то в 2002. А вообще, размер бинарника большой скорее всего из-за большого размера рантайм библиотеки. Попробуйте посмотреть ключи fpc, возможно есть варианты с RELEASE компиляцией, плюс ключи оптимизации.

Comment: @insolor
Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: насколько большой? учтите что там статическая линковка

Comment: Ну для "типичного" helloworld 187Кб как то многовато.
При том, что на Си - 16Кб, а на NASM - 4,4Кб